# What is the difference between these two versions of code (pointer arithmetics & unicode)?

Tags: c, unicode, pointers

I'm debugging some opensource code on a 64-bit Solaris system, using GCC, that converts 2byte characters (`wchar_t`) to 4byte characters (`wchar_t`). Because Solaris like some other Unixes define wchar_t as 4byte, not 2byte like in Windows.

Now I fixed the problem, through laying it out the pointer arithmetic over two lines, but I'm not sure what was wrong with the original code. Any clues?

**Original Code**

```
int StringCopy2to4bytes(const unsigned short* src, int src_size, 
                         unsigned int* dst, int dst_size)
{
 int cp_size = 0;

 const unsigned short *src_end = NULL;
 const unsigned int   *dst_end = NULL;

 unsigned int c1, c2;

 src_end = src + src_size;
 dst_end = dst + dst_size;

 while (src < src_end)
 {
     c1 = *src++;
     if ((c1 >= UNI_SUR_HIGH_START) && (c1 <= UNI_SUR_HIGH_END))
     {
         if (src < src_end)
         {
             c2 = *src;
             if ((c2 >= UNI_SUR_LOW_START) && (c2 <= UNI_SUR_LOW_END))
             {
                c1 = ((c1 - UNI_SUR_HIGH_START) << UNI_SHIFT) + 
                      (c1 - UNI_SUR_LOW_START )  + UNI_BASE;

                ++src;
             }
         } 
         else 
             return -1;
     } 

     if (dst >= dst_end) return -2;

     *dst++ = c1;

     cp_size++;
 }

 return cp_size;
}
```

**Fixed Code**

```
int StringCopy2to4bytes(const unsigned short* src, int src_size, 
                         unsigned int* dst, int dst_size)
{
 int cp_size = 0;

 const unsigned short *src_end = NULL;
 const unsigned int   *dst_end = NULL;

 unsigned int c1, c2;

 src_end = src + src_size;
 dst_end = dst + dst_size;

 while (src < src_end)
 {
     c1 = *src; //FIX
     ++src;

     if ((c1 >= UNI_SUR_HIGH_START) && (c1 <= UNI_SUR_HIGH_END))
     {
         if (src < src_end)
         {
             c2 = *src;
             if ((c2 >= UNI_SUR_LOW_START) && (c2 <= UNI_SUR_LOW_END))
             {
                c1 = ((c1 - UNI_SUR_HIGH_START) << UNI_SHIFT) + 
                      (c1 - UNI_SUR_LOW_START )  + UNI_BASE;

                ++src;
             }
         } 
         else 
             return -1;
     } 

     if (dst >= dst_end) return -2;

     *dst = c1; //FIX
     ++dst;

     cp_size++;
 }

 return cp_size;
}
```

**Edit**: for the record, the code isn't mine, I'm just using it, and happen to be debugging it, not that it makes a big difference, but the source is fairly big, so I'm trying to fix it with tweezers as it may be, not refactor everything, anyways bugs are bugs, and I need to fix it and mail the author about what was wrong.

The constants are:

```
/* unicode constants */
#define UNI_SHIFT             ((int) 10 )
#define UNI_BASE              ((unsigned int) 0x0010000UL)
#define UNI_MASK              ((unsigned int) 0x3FFUL)
#define UNI_REPLACEMENT_CHAR  ((unsigned int) 0x0000FFFD)
#define UNI_MAX_BMP           ((unsigned int) 0x0000FFFF)
#define UNI_MAX_UTF16         ((unsigned int) 0x0010FFFF)
#define UNI_MAX_UTF32         ((unsigned int) 0x7FFFFFFF)
#define UNI_MAX_LEGAL_UTF32   ((unsigned int) 0x0010FFFF)
#define UNI_SUR_HIGH_START    ((unsigned int) 0xD800)
#define UNI_SUR_HIGH_END      ((unsigned int) 0xDBFF)
#define UNI_SUR_LOW_START     ((unsigned int) 0xDC00)
#define UNI_SUR_LOW_END       ((unsigned int) 0xDFFF)
```

Comment: The question is mildly confusing - you can't simultaneously have wchar_t being 2 bytes and 4 bytes.  Also, which version of GCC are you using?

Comment: The OS uses wchar_t(4) but it needs to transmit character data as wchar_t(2) over the network to other systems, so it converts between the two

Comment: The code generated with 4.2.4 for both listings is absolutely identical.

Comment: What are the values of the constants?  I think they might be: enum { UNI_SUR_HIGH_START = 0xD800, UNI_SUR_HIGH_END = 0xDBFF
       UNI_SUR_LOW_START  = 0xDC00, UNI_SUR_LOW_END  = 0xDFFF,
       UNI_SHIFT = 11, UNI_BASE = 0x10000 };
I'm least confident about UNI_BASE.

Comment: well they are #defines, which isn't cool , but you got the values right

Comment: Actually, UNI_SHIFT is 10, not 11 as I quoted...thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code as written here is still buggy - when you combine c1 and c2 you need to use c2!  That is, at the lines:

```
c1 = ((c1 - UNI_SUR_HIGH_START) << UNI_SHIFT) +
      (c1 - UNI_SUR_LOW_START ) + UNI_BASE;
```

The third occurrence of c1 should actually be c2.

Additionally, it seems silly to initialize the src_end pointer to null and then to src + src_size.  Why not get there straight away?

Also, cp_size could redundant if the start of the string was preserved; it would then be the same as (dst - initial_dst).

---

Test code - with c1 to c2 fix - using first code example, on Solaris 10, with GCC 4.3.3.  Results for 32-bit and 64-bit compilation shown.  Data from Table 3.4 in Chapter 3 of the Unicode standard (technically, Unicode 5.0 rather than 5.1.0, but I don't think it matters).

```
enum { NULL = 0 };
enum { UNI_SUR_HIGH_START = 0xD800, UNI_SUR_HIGH_END = 0xDBFF,
       UNI_SUR_LOW_START  = 0xDC00, UNI_SUR_LOW_END  = 0xDFFF,
       UNI_SHIFT = 10, UNI_BASE = 0x10000 };

int StringCopy2to4bytes(const unsigned short* src, int src_size, 
                         unsigned int* dst, int dst_size)
{
 int cp_size = 0;

 const unsigned short *src_end = NULL;
 const unsigned int   *dst_end = NULL;

 unsigned int c1, c2;

 src_end = src + src_size;
 dst_end = dst + dst_size;

 while (src < src_end)
 {
     c1 = *src++;
     if ((c1 >= UNI_SUR_HIGH_START) && (c1 <= UNI_SUR_HIGH_END))
     {
         if (src < src_end)
         {
             c2 = *src;
             if ((c2 >= UNI_SUR_LOW_START) && (c2 <= UNI_SUR_LOW_END))
             {
                c1 = ((c1 - UNI_SUR_HIGH_START) << UNI_SHIFT) + 
                      (c2 - UNI_SUR_LOW_START )  + UNI_BASE;    /* Fixed */

                ++src;
             }
         } 
         else 
             return -1;
     } 

     if (dst >= dst_end) return -2;

     *dst++ = c1;

     cp_size++;
 }

 return cp_size;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned short w2_chars[] = { 0x004D, 0x0430, 0x4E8C, 0xD800, 0xDF02, 0x004D };
    unsigned int   w4_wanted[] = { 0x00004D, 0x000430, 0x004E8C, 0x010302, 0x00004D };
    unsigned int   w4_actual[5];
    int w2_len = 6;
    int w4_len = 5;
    int w4_actlen;
    int i;
    int failed = 0;

    w4_actlen = StringCopy2to4bytes(w2_chars, w2_len, w4_actual, w4_len);
    if (w4_actlen != w4_len)
    {
        failed = 1;
        printf("Length mismatch: got %d, wanted %d\n", w4_actlen, w4_len);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < w4_len; i++)
    {
        if (w4_actual[i] != w4_wanted[i])
        {
            printf("Mismatch: index %d: wanted 0x%06X, actual 0x%06X\n",
                   i, w4_wanted[i], w4_actual[i]);
            failed = 1;
        }
    }
    if (failed == 0)
        printf("No problem observed\n");
    return((failed == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}


$ gcc -m32 -O utf.c -o utf32 && ./utf32
No problem observed
$ gcc -m64 -O utf.c -o utf64 && ./utf64
No problem observed
$
```

I'm left wondering what is up with your compiler - or your test case.

---

Here's a revised version of the StringCopy2to4bytes() function.  It detects and reports an error condition that the original did not - namely when the second word of  surrogate pair is not a valid low surrogate code point, it returns status -3.

```
int StringCopy2to4bytes(const unsigned short *src, int src_size, 
                        unsigned int *dst, int dst_size)
{
    const unsigned short *src_end = src + src_size;
    const unsigned int   *dst_end = dst + dst_size;
    const unsigned int   *dst0    = dst;

    while (src < src_end)
    {
        unsigned int c1 = *src++;
        if ((c1 >= UNI_SUR_HIGH_START) && (c1 <= UNI_SUR_HIGH_END))
        {
            if (src >= src_end)
                return -1;
            unsigned int c2 = *src++;
            if ((c2 >= UNI_SUR_LOW_START) && (c2 <= UNI_SUR_LOW_END))
            {
               c1 = ((c1 - UNI_SUR_HIGH_START) << UNI_SHIFT) + 
                     (c2 - UNI_SUR_LOW_START )  + UNI_BASE;    /* Fixed */
            }
            else
                return -3;  /* Invalid second code point in surrogate pair */
        } 
        if (dst >= dst_end)
            return -2; 
        *dst++ = c1;
    }
    return dst - dst0;
}
```

The same test code produces the same clean bill of health.  The declaration of c2 assumes you are using C99 - not C89.

Comment: I think he's talking about lines 24/25 from example 1. I wonder if the pointer arithmetic is a red herring where the problem is really this.

Comment: Added the values of the constants to the question

Comment: Thanks for the Unicode fix! Anyways the issue was a rare buffer overflow not the pointer arithmetics:/

Comment: Had to add unicode to the question so this could be an answer :)

Comment: @Robert - Just curious was the buffer overflow a bug in this routine or was an incorrect size being passed in (for example, size in bytes instead of size in chars)?

Comment: A buffer overflow makes more sense than a compiler bug, which was an outside possibility at most.  I'm as curious as Michael about how the buffer overflow occurred.  The function basically looks sound and safe, so I assume it was being misused.

Comment: The buffer was shorter than the advertised size. Specifically some buffer sizes were being rounded to even numbers, when they should have been, say buffer[3] was actually buffer[2], so it was writing out of bounds

Comment: That'll do it every time. Compilers object when you lie to them, and usually find a way to get their own back.  Bad luck on having to debug someone else's buffer overflows.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like we could need some () here.

Look at the difference

1. c1 = *src++;
2. c1 = (*src)++;
3. c1 = *(src++);

I really like () since they remove some ambiguity on what the programmer wants to do.

/Johan

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a difference, ++ binds higher than *.

A quick test.c doesn't show any difference, either:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int * p = a;
    printf( "%d\n", *p );
    printf( "%d\n", *p++ );
    printf( "%d\n", *p );
    printf( "%d\n", *(p++) );
    printf( "%d\n", *p );
    return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
0
0
1
1
2
```

What makes you think you had a problem that the new code fixed?

**Edit:** Finding a compiler bug in something **that** trivial is highly unlikely. Above test was run with GCC 4.1.2.

**Edit 2:** You've got some type mismatches there. c1 is unsigned int, *src is unsigned short. Sizes should be size_t, not int. Does the problem with the original code persist if you fix those?

Comment: I agree with that Sizes should be size_t but the entire code base uses int for sizes, and does some checks against size > -1, so I can't change it very easily.

Comment: Erm... yes you can? Simply use size_t where sizes are required. Any int will be casted to size_t automatically. Yes, that's still a type mismatch, but it's at the interface between "your code" and "old code"...

Haven't checked the algorithm, Jonathan has some things to say about that...